# Kohana auth counting get_user as a login?

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-orm, kohana-auth

I am messing about with KO3 and the auth module, I have logins working quite well, but I have noticed that every time I refresh the page the login count for my user increments.

I am pretty sure it is coming from this section.

```
// Check if logged in
if ($this->auth->logged_in())
{
    // Pass user to view
    $this->view->user = $this->auth->get_user(); // Here?
}
else
{
    // Attempt auto login
    $this->auth->auto_login();

    // Check if logged in
    if ($this->auth->logged_in())
    {
        // Pass user to view
        $this->view->user = $this->auth->get_user();
    }
}
```

Now I am pretty sure it is the line where I pass the users object to the view. The line commented with `// Here?`.

I just wondered why this would increment the logins. I have checked out the source and all it is doing is reading the session variables.

**EDIT**

I thought I had this fixed after I had it explained to me. Apparently not. I am not pretty sure it is down to sessions, I have tried using the cookie and session classes from the GitHub repo but that made no difference.

I am not sure where to begin debugging this.

Comment: I am guessing this is not an easy question to answer.

Comment: Does session works correctly? I think, the problem is with `auto_login()` call.

Comment: @biakaveron Yep, the sessions where fine, Kemo has shown me what was wrong. `logged_in` calls `auto_login` thus logging in on every page view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overseeing the fact that your whole else block is ambigous, because a single call to Auth_ORM::logged_in() causes the following:

```
Auth_ORM::logged_in() 
-> Auth_ORM::get_user() 
-> Auth_ORM::auto_login()
-> Auth_ORM::complete_login()
-> Model_Auth_User::complete_login()
```

So your code would practically do the same looking like this:

```
// Check if logged in
if ($this->auth->logged_in())
{
    // Pass user to view
    $this->view->user = $this->auth->get_user();
}
```

And `Model_Auth_User::complete_login()` is where the logins count gets incremented.

Your problem is that `Auth_ORM::auto_login()` is always called (either because of a PEBKAC or your session isn't ok), setting a new token instead of saving the user object into session.

Comment: I never knew `logged_in` called `auto_login`! Thank you so much for explaining that. I guess I would have known if there had been any documentation. Come on, [empty docs](http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/auth)? Thanks again, you have been a real help.

Comment: I disagree with it. As you can see (https://github.com/kohana/auth/blob/3.0%2Fmaster/classes/kohana/auth/orm.php#L192), `get_user()` method will call `auto_login()` only if your session has no `User` object (https://github.com/kohana/auth/blob/3.0%2Fmaster/classes/kohana/auth.php#L87). Its true when you open a page first time (session just created), but after refresh Auth will gets a `User` object. Thats why I ask you about session work.

Comment: Hmm... I missed Kemo's last paragraph :)

Comment: @biakaveron I see, I did not read the last sentence either >_> I think it is down to my session, but I do not know what. I have a salt, nothing really complicated is going on.

Comment: May be its because your session is regenerated every request? How do check it?

Comment: Well I get a new instance and run logged in every time, even with the fixed code @Kemo suggested without the else statement it just keeps logging in. It is as if it can not retain the session variable.